# pine script. merging 2 charts into one

Tags: charts, merge, pine-script

I am searching for a pine-script that calculates an average-chart out of 2 given chart-symbols an after that shows me the MA200 of the newly generated chart. Does anybody has this? Or knows how to do?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can get the close price of both contracts using request.security. Then you can find average of two closes and plot it. Then you can find sma of avg and plot it.

Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Indicator Merge By Rohit",overlay=true)
symbol1 = input.symbol("CL1!","Symbol1")
symbol2 = input.symbol("UKOIL","Symbol2")
close1=request.security(symbol1, timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off)
close2=request.security(symbol2,timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off)
avg=(close1+close2)/2
plot(avg)
plot(ta.sma(avg,200))
```